# React Twitter OAuth Callback Status Code 401

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, callback

Wanted to test Twitter OAuth callback with my React app on localhost.
Saw that you could use `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in the Twitter App Console for both Website and Callback URL fields for it to work with localhost.

```
const twitterStream = new Twitter(twitterConfig.TWITTER_CONFIG);
```

I am using the `twitter` npm and getting the following 401 status code error --

```
Error: Status Code: 401
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Projects/project-name/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:277:28)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Request.onRequestResponse (/Users/me/Projects/pproject-name/node_modules/request/request.js:986:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:474:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback` as the callback URL in application settings back on Twitter.

Comment: i've updated the callback URL to the above, and getting the same error